# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i^p}$ can be written as $\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1} + An^p + Bn^{p-1}+Cn^{p-2}+\cdots$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation

Let $p$ be an positive integer. Show that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i^p}$ can be written in the form $$\frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1} + An^p + Bn^{p-1}+Cn^{p-2}+\cdots$$
I tried prove it using induction on $p$.
Notice that the proposition works for:
$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i}=\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{2}$$
$$\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i^2}=\frac{n^3}{3}+\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{6}$$
Then, assuming the induction hypothesis. I must show that for $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i^{p+1}}$ but i get stuck here. Maybe I could use the telescopic formula that we use to prove the summation of simple powers ($\sum_{i=1}^{n}[(i+1)^p-i^p]$) but it would be too cumbersome or, Faulhaber's formula but, isn't there a more direct way to prove it?.

Comment: Exactly the same question was closed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4875275

Comment: @Gary what was wrong with the question anyway?

Comment: @lcv That version has been improved since closing and is now re-opened. Since this one has been answered, I recommend that the OP delete the old version.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\Delta$ be the difference operator $\Delta f(n) = f(n) - f(n-1)$.  Since (using the binomial theorem) $$\Delta(n^k) = n^k - (n-1)^k = - \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} {k \choose j} n^j (-1)^{k-j}$$
$\Delta$ maps the space $P_d$ of polynomials of degree $\le d$ to $P_{d-1}$ for
any $d \ge 1$.  Note also that the leading term of $\Delta(n^k)$ is ${n \choose k-1} n^{k-1} = k n^{k-1}$, and more generally if $p$ is a polynomial of degree $k$, $\Delta p$ is a polynomial of degree $k-1$ with leading coefficient $k$ times the leading coefficient of $p$. Since the null space of this linear map is the constant polynomials, and $P_d$ has dimension one greater than $P_{d-1}$, it is onto,
i.e. for any polynomial $p$ of degree $ d$ there is a polynomial $q$ of degree $d+1$ such that $\Delta q = p$.  Note that
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n p(i) = \sum_{i=1}^n (q(i) - q(i-1)) = q(n) - q(0) $$ which is a polynomial of degree $d+1$, and the leading coefficient of $q(n) - q(0)$ is $1/(d+1)$ times the leading coefficient of $p(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply observe that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \left (\frac{k}{n} \right )^p = \int_0^1 dx \,  x^p = \frac{1}{p+1}
$$

Therefore

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k^p = \frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1} +O(n^p) \tag{1}
$$

which is essentially what you wrote.

**Added**

Strictly speaking, we only know that the remainder in the Riemann sum grows slower than $n^{p+1}$, more precisely that the remainder is $o(n^{p+1})$.
However it is known that the the error in the right Riemann sum satisfies:

$$
\left \vert \int_0^1 dx \, f(x) - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f(k/n) \right \vert \le \frac{1}{2n} \max_{x\in[0,1]} f'(x) 
$$

see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Right_rule).

So the error term in $(1)$ is really of order of $n^p$.

Comment: I don't think that's what he needs. The claim is stronger:  there's a polynomial $f\in\mathbb Q[x]$ with leading coeficient $\frac{1}{p+1}$ s.t. $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n i^p = f(n)\ \forall n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: @LucasHenrique I understand what you mean, but frankly that's not what's written in the post.